# Yii как правильно сделать выборку?

Tags: ооп, php, yii, sql

в бд есть категории, есть типы. каждый тип принадлежит своей категории. с помощью gii сгенерировал контроллер TypeController, в котором метод index передает все типы в виде объекта класса CActiveDataProvider в вид. допустим, я хочу выбрать типы принадлежащие определенной категории. таким образом в объект CActiveDataProvider добавляю в параметры `array('criteria'=>array('condition'=>'category_id='.$id)`.
правильно ли так делать в критериях и есть ли угроза sql инъекции при передаче параметров в объект CDbCriteria? заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`CDbCriteria params`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#params-detail), тогда код будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
array(
  'condition' => 'category_id = :cid',
  'params' => array(':cid' => $id),
);
```

Comment: как раз думал, раз yii просит pdo, то должна быть такая штука. только не нашел что-то. спасибо